# non-static method encode(byte[]) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

```
package com.cordys.report;

import java.io.FileInputStream; 

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


public class Encode {
public static String encodeFileStream(String filePath) //file path ex : C:\Program Files\Cordys\Web\reports\I0001180.pdf
{    
try {
   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("E:/CSS Document/Test.pdf");
   StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
   int lineLength = 72;
   byte[] buf = new byte[lineLength/4*3];
   while (true) {
     int len = fin.read(buf);
     if (len <= 0) {
      break;
     }
    sb.append(Base64.encode(buf));

   return sb.toString();
 }
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
   return e.getMessage();
 }
}



}
```

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790826/non-static-method-encodebyte-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context Even the class used is the same.

Comment: okay, so far you've managed to make six non-registered accounts.  I've merged them [into this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/587133/monika).  Please, REGISTER an account (you've asked six questions, its about time) and then FLAG this one.  When you flag, select Other, and ask me to merge your account into your registered one.

Answer (score 10):

As seen at http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

try `Base64.encodeBase64()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Method `Base64.encode()` is not `static`. You have to create instance of class `Base64` and then invoke the method, i.e. do something like `new Base64().encode(bytes)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) object and call `encode` on the object as the method is not static, thus it can only be called from an instance of its enclosing class.

```
Base64 b = new Base64();
sb.append(b.encode(buf));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried it but again it throws error Missing return statement.

Comment: @monika just put return null; before your line }catch(Exception e)

Comment: @david actually the return should be outside of the try/catch block as there is no guarantee that the return would be reached if it was inside.